# Azure load balancing Round Robin and VM Instance IDs

Tags: c#, azure, httprequest, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine

Hi I am working with a single http endpoint that i can send requests to. I am working with Azure load balancer which should balance requests between 4 VMs. 
According to what i have read so far. The load balancer should use a round robin method to do the routing.

How do I make http requests in such a way that I am sure I have hit all the VMs and not just the first VM. I suppose I must do a concurrent request of some sort. Maybe an asynchrounous **parallel** request? The VMs have identical data so its pertinent that I hit all 4 VMs with 4 requests. I hope my question is clear enough

Also I have the VM server instance Id's. How do i use the id's to specify the server i want to hit in the request.

Comment: Azure Load balancer is not RR (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-distribution-mode). Other services could be (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-load-balancing-azure). Can you clarify ""its pertinent that I hit all 4 VMs with 4 requests".

Comment: Yes i need to somehow tell the server which vm i want to hit in my request. I am new to this so i dont know if there are default headers forexample that allow specifying the server instance

Comment: I think that you are looking at the wrong infrastructure pattern as you should probably be trying not to direct your traffic to a specific server (unless you are after "sticky sessions" which can sort of be achieved using "Source IP affinity mode" again see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-distribution-mode. Can you update your question to reflect what you are trying to achieve and maybe why?

Answer (score 1):

> The load balancer should use a round robin method to do the routing.

As JohnMark13 said, Azure load balancer have two modes: `Hash-based distribution mode` and `Source IP affinity mode`.

For now, Azure Load balancer does **not** support specify VM id to access it, just support IP address + port.

As a workaround, I think we can set **NAT rules**, set different ports to different VMs, so we can access different VMs with IP address and different ports.

[image]
More information about Azure load balancer and NAT rules, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-portal#create-a-probe-lb-rule-and-nat-rules).

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)